# Can't connect from docker container to another. Connection refused

Tags: docker, networking

I'm trying to establish a connection from one docker container to another using telnet, however I get "telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused" error all the time.

Commands I've executed so far:

```
docker run -dit --name nA --net mynet -p 8081:80 -p 1001:443 test_image:1.0 bash

docker run -dit --name nB --net mynet -p 8080:80 -p 1000:443 test_image:1.0 bash
```

That's the output from docker inspect mynet

```
"Containers": {
        "1df3f3821710b3f8103fe79e338d709a93baf301dafc015bb5f1e162bca206de": {
            "Name": "nB",
            "EndpointID": "bf7cbc2e60ddb99cd3b8bd416b066787840ced6de74eb1961b4f9663a28fdd80",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:13:00:03",
            "IPv4Address": "172.19.0.3/16",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        },
        "7aea617e121eda0884ae7ce46e1534800af2d30822f3899f69c4165a40c1370d": {
            "Name": "nA",
            "EndpointID": "7a60026517ff0b1b337a5af9ccf8d7dc9c896606196bcb1bafe537e6fddaa8dc",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:13:00:02",
            "IPv4Address": "172.19.0.2/16",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        }
    },
```

Ping works perfectly:

```
root@1df3f3821710:/# ping nA
PING nA (172.19.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from nA.mynet (172.19.0.2): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.141 ms
64 bytes from nA.mynet (172.19.0.2): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.261 ms
```

Then I'm trying to connect from one container to another using the ports that has been published.

```
root@1df3f3821710:/# telnet nA 8081
Trying 172.19.0.2...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
root@1df3f3821710:/# telnet nA 1001
Trying 172.19.0.2...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
root@1df3f3821710:/# telnet nA 80
Trying 172.19.0.2...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
root@1df3f3821710:/# telnet nA 443
Trying 172.19.0.2...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

The same happens when connecting from the other container.

```
root@7aea617e121e:/# telnet nB 8080
Trying 172.19.0.3...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
root@7aea617e121e:/# telnet nB 80  
Trying 172.19.0.3...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
root@7aea617e121e:/# telnet nB 1000
Trying 172.19.0.3...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
root@7aea617e121e:/# telnet nB 443 
Trying 172.19.0.3...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

What is the problem here?

Docker version: 17.09.0
OSes: Mac and Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The published ports are available from the host, they aren't used for inter container communication.
2. You are overriding whatever command defined for your image and starting bash instead, so thats the only process running on your container and your applications inside the container aren't starting at all.

What you meant to do is the following

```
docker run -d --name nA --net mynet -p 8081:80 -p 1001:443 test_image:1.0
docker run -d --name nB --net mynet -p 8080:80 -p 1000:443 test_image:1.0
```

Then connect to the running containers

```
$ docker exec -it nA bash

$ docker exec -it nB bash
```

Comment: Actually it was not all the commands I executed. I ran a few services inside the containers before testing connectivity. After your comment it's obvious now that the services must have crushed at some point cause all the mess here. Thank you!

Comment: I agree that ports 808? and 100? are not available for inter container communication but why not port 80 (and perhaps also 443) ?